# Chromium and SELinux

Tags: linux, centos, security, selinux, chrome

I need to run Chromium via Puppeteer in the browser but I am getting a few SElinux alerts. If I create an `audit2allow` module for the alerts, the alerts disappear but Chromium still does not run. As soon as I set SElinux back to `permissive` mode Chromium runs again.

I'm not sure what to do here. How can I fix the errors below so I can use SElinux in enforcing mode?

I can also get Chromium working if I set `httpd` to permissive while SElinux is still in `enforcing` mode with `semanage permissive -a httpd_t`, but I'm guessing the is a big security issue?

All the SElinux alerts are in the `/var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-624492/chrome-linux/chrome` directory so I guess I need to give these directory/files a particular label but which one?

OS: CentOS 7.6

```
SELinux is preventing /var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-624492/chrome-linux/chrome from using the sys_admin capability.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that chrome should have the sys_admin capability by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'chrome' --raw | audit2allow -M my-chrome
# semodule -i my-chrome.pp


Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Objects                Unknown [ capability ]
Source                        chrome
Source Path                   /var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-
                              chromium/linux-624492/chrome-linux/chrome
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          di-staging
Source RPM Packages
Target RPM Packages
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.13.1-229.el7_6.6.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Permissive
Host Name                     di-staging
Platform                      Linux di-staging 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu
                              Nov 8 23:39:32 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   7
First Seen                    2019-03-02 16:33:12 GMT
Last Seen                     2019-03-03 13:00:18 GMT
Local ID                      ff2cf4a9-6788-4027-8986-fc1db4f026b3

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1551618018.451:581328): avc:  denied  { sys_admin } for  pid=15865 comm="chrome" capability=21  scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tclass=capability permissive=1


type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1551618018.451:581328): arch=x86_64 syscall=open success=yes exit=ECONNREFUSED a0=559709404bb0 a1=1 a2=20 a3=7ffe9f76fba0 items=0 ppid=15863 pid=15865 auid=4294967295 uid=996 gid=993 euid=996 suid=996 fsuid=996 egid=993 sgid=993 fsgid=993 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=chrome exe=/var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-624492/chrome-linux/chrome subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)

Hash: chrome,httpd_t,httpd_t,capability,sys_admin
```

```
SELinux is preventing /var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-624492/chrome-linux/chrome from using the sys_ptrace capability.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that chrome should have the sys_ptrace capability by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'chrome' --raw | audit2allow -M my-chrome
# semodule -i my-chrome.pp


Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Objects                Unknown [ capability ]
Source                        chrome
Source Path                   /var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-
                              chromium/linux-624492/chrome-linux/chrome
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          di-staging
Source RPM Packages
Target RPM Packages
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.13.1-229.el7_6.6.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Permissive
Host Name                     di-staging
Platform                      Linux di-staging 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu
                              Nov 8 23:39:32 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   8
First Seen                    2019-03-02 16:32:26 GMT
Last Seen                     2019-03-03 13:00:18 GMT
Local ID                      195b1636-4c46-47b9-92d2-19323a2e05a8

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1551618018.527:581330): avc:  denied  { sys_ptrace } for  pid=15863 comm="chrome" capability=19  scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tclass=capability permissive=1


type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1551618018.527:581330): arch=x86_64 syscall=read success=yes exit=364 a0=70 a1=35eabe34f000 a2=10000 a3=22 items=0 ppid=15848 pid=15863 auid=4294967295 uid=996 gid=993 euid=996 suid=996 fsuid=996 egid=993 sgid=993 fsgid=993 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=chrome exe=/var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-624492/chrome-linux/chrome subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)

Hash: chrome,httpd_t,httpd_t,capability,sys_ptrace
```

```
SELinux is preventing /var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-624492/chrome-linux/chrome from create access on the netlink_kobject_uevent_socket labeled httpd_t.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that chrome should be allowed create access on netlink_kobject_uevent_socket labeled httpd_t by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'Chrome_IOThread' --raw | audit2allow -M my-ChromeIOThread
# semodule -i my-ChromeIOThread.pp


Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Objects                Unknown [ netlink_kobject_uevent_socket ]
Source                        Chrome_IOThread
Source Path                   /var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-
                              chromium/linux-624492/chrome-linux/chrome
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          di-staging
Source RPM Packages
Target RPM Packages
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.13.1-229.el7_6.6.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Permissive
Host Name                     di-staging
Platform                      Linux di-staging 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu
                              Nov 8 23:39:32 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   8
First Seen                    2019-03-02 16:32:26 GMT
Last Seen                     2019-03-03 13:00:18 GMT
Local ID                      9e4b0c7f-78a5-4585-be26-db09f9309f6f

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1551618018.602:581331): avc:  denied  { create } for  pid=15863 comm="Chrome_IOThread" scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tclass=netlink_kobject_uevent_socket permissive=1


type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1551618018.602:581331): arch=x86_64 syscall=socket success=yes exit=151 a0=10 a1=80803 a2=f a3=35eabe431060 items=0 ppid=15848 pid=15863 auid=4294967295 uid=996 gid=993 euid=996 suid=996 fsuid=996 egid=993 sgid=993 fsgid=993 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=Chrome_IOThread exe=/var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-624492/chrome-linux/chrome subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)

Hash: Chrome_IOThread,httpd_t,httpd_t,netlink_kobject_uevent_socket,create
```

```
SELinux is preventing /var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-624492/chrome-linux/chrome from setopt access on the netlink_kobject_uevent_socket labeled httpd_t.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that chrome should be allowed setopt access on netlink_kobject_uevent_socket labeled httpd_t by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'Chrome_IOThread' --raw | audit2allow -M my-ChromeIOThread
# semodule -i my-ChromeIOThread.pp


Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Objects                Unknown [ netlink_kobject_uevent_socket ]
Source                        Chrome_IOThread
Source Path                   /var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-
                              chromium/linux-624492/chrome-linux/chrome
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          di-staging
Source RPM Packages
Target RPM Packages
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.13.1-229.el7_6.6.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Permissive
Host Name                     di-staging
Platform                      Linux di-staging 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu
                              Nov 8 23:39:32 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   8
First Seen                    2019-03-02 16:32:26 GMT
Last Seen                     2019-03-03 13:00:18 GMT
Local ID                      59f8fbbf-0ce1-4dd3-94ff-8fd5eb13696f

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1551618018.603:581332): avc:  denied  { setopt } for  pid=15863 comm="Chrome_IOThread" scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tclass=netlink_kobject_uevent_socket permissive=1


type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1551618018.603:581332): arch=x86_64 syscall=setsockopt success=yes exit=0 a0=97 a1=1 a2=1a a3=7fe1ed084420 items=0 ppid=15848 pid=15863 auid=4294967295 uid=996 gid=993 euid=996 suid=996 fsuid=996 egid=993 sgid=993 fsgid=993 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=Chrome_IOThread exe=/var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-624492/chrome-linux/chrome subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)

Hash: Chrome_IOThread,httpd_t,httpd_t,netlink_kobject_uevent_socket,setopt
```

```
SELinux is preventing /var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-624492/chrome-linux/chrome from bind access on the netlink_kobject_uevent_socket labeled httpd_t.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that chrome should be allowed bind access on netlink_kobject_uevent_socket labeled httpd_t by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'Chrome_IOThread' --raw | audit2allow -M my-ChromeIOThread
# semodule -i my-ChromeIOThread.pp


Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Objects                Unknown [ netlink_kobject_uevent_socket ]
Source                        Chrome_IOThread
Source Path                   /var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-
                              chromium/linux-624492/chrome-linux/chrome
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          di-staging
Source RPM Packages
Target RPM Packages
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.13.1-229.el7_6.6.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Permissive
Host Name                     di-staging
Platform                      Linux di-staging 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu
                              Nov 8 23:39:32 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   8
First Seen                    2019-03-02 16:32:26 GMT
Last Seen                     2019-03-03 13:00:18 GMT
Local ID                      b50937b0-a30a-4724-8c8d-d50077ae5e1a

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1551618018.603:581333): avc:  denied  { bind } for  pid=15863 comm="Chrome_IOThread" scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tclass=netlink_kobject_uevent_socket permissive=1


type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1551618018.603:581333): arch=x86_64 syscall=bind success=yes exit=0 a0=97 a1=35eabe384a10 a2=c a3=7fe1ed084420 items=0 ppid=15848 pid=15863 auid=4294967295 uid=996 gid=993 euid=996 suid=996 fsuid=996 egid=993 sgid=993 fsgid=993 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=Chrome_IOThread exe=/var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-624492/chrome-linux/chrome subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)

Hash: Chrome_IOThread,httpd_t,httpd_t,netlink_kobject_uevent_socket,bind
```

```
SELinux is preventing /var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-624492/chrome-linux/chrome from getattr access on the netlink_kobject_uevent_socket labeled httpd_t.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that chrome should be allowed getattr access on netlink_kobject_uevent_socket labeled httpd_t by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'Chrome_IOThread' --raw | audit2allow -M my-ChromeIOThread
# semodule -i my-ChromeIOThread.pp


Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Objects                Unknown [ netlink_kobject_uevent_socket ]
Source                        Chrome_IOThread
Source Path                   /var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-
                              chromium/linux-624492/chrome-linux/chrome
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          di-staging
Source RPM Packages
Target RPM Packages
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.13.1-229.el7_6.6.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Permissive
Host Name                     di-staging
Platform                      Linux di-staging 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu
                              Nov 8 23:39:32 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   8
First Seen                    2019-03-02 16:32:26 GMT
Last Seen                     2019-03-03 13:00:18 GMT
Local ID                      889a731e-830f-4ae8-8a66-bfdb0532629e

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1551618018.603:581334): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=15863 comm="Chrome_IOThread" scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tclass=netlink_kobject_uevent_socket permissive=1


type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1551618018.603:581334): arch=x86_64 syscall=getsockname success=yes exit=0 a0=97 a1=7fe1ed085490 a2=7fe1ed08548c a3=7fe1ed084420 items=0 ppid=15848 pid=15863 auid=4294967295 uid=996 gid=993 euid=996 suid=996 fsuid=996 egid=993 sgid=993 fsgid=993 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=Chrome_IOThread exe=/var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-624492/chrome-linux/chrome subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)

Hash: Chrome_IOThread,httpd_t,httpd_t,netlink_kobject_uevent_socket,getattr
```

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get Chromium working while keeping SElinux and httpd in enforcing mode, but it means using a label which effectively sets Chromium into permissive mode:

[httpd_unconfined_script_exec_t](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/managing_confined_services/sect-managing_confined_services-the_apache_http_server-types)

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_unconfined_script_exec_t '/var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium(/.*)?/chrome-linux/chrome'

sudo restorecon -R -v '/var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/'
```

I'll wait a while before marking this as the answer because I'm still hoping to find a better solution from someone.